# geom_contour: select/color only one of the contour lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make one contour line created by geom_contour a separate color than the others? For example, in the below code how can I keep all contour lines black except the one labeled 0.02, which I'd like to be a color other than used by the rest.

```
require(directlabels)
p <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) + 
     geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = ..level..))
p <- direct.label(p, list("bottom.pieces", cex = .6))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) + 
  geom_contour(aes(z = density, 
                   colour = factor(..level.. == 0.02, 
                                   levels = c(F, T), 
                                   labels = c("Others", "0.02"))),
               breaks = 0.005*0:10) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red")) + 
  labs(colour = "Of interest:")
```

[image]

This is a fairly extensible way to do it. All the "FALSE" values for `..level.. == 0.02` will show as black, while the "TRUE" show as red. To get this to work properly, I needed to set the breaks to line up with *exactly* 0.02 (and other multiples of 0.05), which is what the `breaks =` does.

Comment: Which after playing with it, I see that those are still the actual breaks if you don't call `breaks = 0.05*0:10`. Not sure why it didn't work without specifying them.

Comment: Thanks. That's almost exactly what I need, except I still need to be able to label the contours. When I try using your suggestion I can't get it to work with direct.labels.

Comment: I tried using that package once and didn't have any luck with it, so I'm afraid I can't troubleshoot that part.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up overlaying two `geom_contour` as the solution, one tied to the `color = ..level..` so that `direct.label` would work, and the other highlighting a particular contour:

```
require(directlabels)
p <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) + 
  geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = ..level..)) +
  scale_color_continuous(low = "black", high = "black") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = ..level..), breaks = .02, color = "red")
p <- direct.label(p, list("bottom.pieces", cex = .6))
```